# Wireless connection drops then password rejected on 12.04

Tags: wireless, networking, acer

I'm using an Acer Aspire 7520, with a AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter with a clean install of 12.04 from disk.

On bootup my wireless connection works automatically, for a while. Then after about 10/20 minutes of use, the connection drops, and when it attempts to reconnect it repeatedly asks me for the wireless password. As the password is pre-entered I click Connect, and wait a minute or so while it attempts to connect, then it asks again, as if the router hasn't accepted the password this time. If I reboot, it connects no problem...for while then the process repeats.

I tried adding blacklist acer_wmi to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf, but this had no effect.

Anyone got any suggestions?

{edit} /var/log/syslog shows: ath5k phy0: gain calibration timeout (2467MHz)

There's a bunch of lines like this. Anyone got a clue what that means?

Comment: I'd check my logs if I were you. The relevant one should be dmesg [driver messages]. They can be found in /var/logs/ folder. See if you can trace back to when you lost the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to look in the logs. Edited the question with info from syslog

Comment: ok, I'll try and look at your lsmod, do you want to send a link to pastebin or something? [for completion type lsmod into terminal and upload the results somewhere convenient]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug with kernel 3.2.

This bug report shows more.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/983025

I upgraded the kernel to 3.5, and now all is well.

Thanks for the help.